# Vegan substitute for down sleeping bags?

Tags: veganism, substitutes, travel, down

I'm looking for a vegan substitute to sleeping bags stuffed with [down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_feather) (eg goose feathers).

I've used both down and synthetic sleeping bags, and the synthetic sleeping bag that gets typically sold in regular outdoor stores tends to be heavier, more bulky, and only comfortable in a (much) smaller temperature range.

Are there other synthetic materials that share the advantages of down sleeping bags but that are not based on animal products?

Comment: For sleeping bags specifically? Or in general?

Comment: Down is most often used in pillows, blankets, and beds.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk Sleeping bags specifically (otherwise it is too broad a question).

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much.

Comment: I disagree with your assumption. There are compact, synthetic sleeping bags that reach down to very low temperatures (e.g. by [Mammut](https://www.mammut.ch/DE/en_DE/B2C-Kategorie/Men/Kompakt-MTI-Winter/p/2410-01741-5604)).

Comment: It took me a few moments to realise that "down" refers to the fur/feathers of animals and not a direction.

Answer (score 4):

There are higher end synthetics available that are much better than the regular poly fill stuff you see in average bags.

The two main companies for better performing synthetic insulation are Climashield and Primaloft. Both offer several levels for insulation and some differing technical aspects. Many brands even the more common ones you find in regular outdoor stores probably offer bags with either of these insulation you just have to look for the tags. They will usually have a separate tag that says what insulation it is and some of the marketing and technical details.

Brands to look for that offer these insulations. That I know can be found in chain outdoor shops in the US, Canada, and Parts of Europe like REI, MEC, Cotswolds, and Unterwegs. All of these stores also offer international shipping for online orders as far as I know.

- Marmot
- The North Face
- Mountain Hardware
- Kelty
- Mountain Equipment

I'm fond of Climashield personally and have two quilts, an older one with the original Climashield Combat and just this week received a custom made quilt with Climashield Apex 200.

Comment: could you please add where these products are available to internationalise your answer a bit? :)

Answer (score 3):

To help you find a perfect match a somewhat more specific set of requirements would be needed, but these should be okay for even low temperatures and should be pretty down like.

**Heavier ones (5-6 lbs; 2–3 kg):**

- [Big Agnes Whiskey Park](https://www.rei.com/product/895940/big-agnes-whiskey-park-0-sleeping-bag?cm_mmc=aff_AL-_-130369-_-157325-_-NA&avad=157325_cd6df5bf) - 0 degrees Fahrenheit / -18 degrees
  Celsius
- [Marmot Trestles](https://www.rei.com/product/107472/marmot-trestles-0-sleeping-bag-mens?cm_mmc=aff_AL-_-130369-_-157325-_-NA&avad=157325_fe0280eb) - 0 degrees Fahrenheit / -18 degrees Celsius

**Lighter ones (3-4 lbs; 1–2 kg):**

- [Mountain Hardwear Hyperlamina Torch](https://www.rei.com/product/880128/mountain-hardwear-hyperlamina-torch-sleeping-bag?cm_mmc=aff_AL-_-130369-_-157325-_-NA&avad=157325_ee02583f) - 3 degrees Fahrenheit / -16
  degrees Celsius
- [REI Co-op Lumen](https://www.rei.com/product/879477/rei-co-op-lumen-sleeping-bag?cm_mmc=aff_AL-_-130369-_-157325-_-NA&avad=157325_de01bdf7) - 20 degrees Fahrenheit / -4 degrees Celsius